# necesito ayuda saber si esta bien este codigo en c

Tags: c

tengo que mostrar un vector en forma recursiva, necesito saber si esta bien la funcion que hice. Mi duda es porque no logro mostrar mas q el primer elemento del vector y tuve q meter un for pero casi segura que esta mal. Por favor si me pueden ayudar

```
void mostrar_v(int vector[]){
    int pos=0,tam=0;
    if(vector[tam]>5){exit(-1);
    }
    for(tam=0;tam<5;tam++){
     if(vector[tam]>0){
     printf("[%d] = %d\n", pos++, vector[tam]);
     }}

         mostrar_v(vector[tam]);
```

Comment: Saludos Adriana, bienvenida a SOes, te recomiendo mirar el tour: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio, de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. Recuerdo muy poco sobre C, sin embargo, sé que este tutorial te ayudará mucho: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/index.htm buenas vibras :D

Comment: Una función recursiva se llama a sí misma (directa o indirectamente), este código no es recursivo.

Comment: muchas gracias! voy a revisar el tutorial y el codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate si ésta solución te sirve:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mostrar_v(int vector[], int pos, int tam)
{
    printf("[%d] = %d\n", pos, vector[pos]);
    if(++pos < tam)
        mostrar_v(vector, pos, tam); // Llamada recursiva
}
void main()
{
    int vector[] = {0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9}; // Vector de prueba
    mostrar_v(vector, 0, sizeof(vector)/sizeof(int));
}
```

A mi me dá el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]